# Update RecordSet using AddNew with data control

Tags: vb6, recordset

I've got a grid which gets it's data source from a 'Data' control that is bound to the grid. I want to add data from another record set into this record set.

What I've got so far is:

```
If rs.BOF = False Then
   rs.MoveFirst
End If

Do Until rs.EOF
   With Dta_Lines.Recordset
      .AddNew
      !Quantity_Ordered = rs.Fields(2)
      !Stock_Code = CStr(rs.Fields(1))
   End With

   rs.MoveNext
Loop

Dta_Lines.RecordSet.Update
Dta_Lines.RecordSet.Refresh
```

However, this isn't populating the grid correctly. The new row remains blank, then gets removed once the `Refresh` method is called.

How do I change this so that the grid adds a new row and the `Stock_Code` and `Quantity_Ordered` values are populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My VB6 knowledge is only very limited, however, have you tried putting the `.Update` call inside the `With` block?

I think in it's current structure, it will be adding a new row but not saving it because each loop overwrites the previously added row since the changes aren't being committed.

```
Do Until rs.EOF
   With Dta_Lines.Recordset
     .AddNew
     !Quantity_Ordered = rs.Fields(2)
     !Stock_Code = CStr(rs.Fields(1))
     .Update
  End With

  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Subtle change, but I think it should do the trick.